# Обработка выхода из функции при остановке программы пользователем

Tags: python, linux, windows, исключения, обработка-сигналов

Есть программа следующей структуры:

```
def compute_res(fails=5):
    res = []
    
    for i in range(1, 1000000):
         try:
             x = str(do_long_stuff())
         except LongStuffException:
             fails -= 1
             if fails == 0:
                 return res

         res.append(x)

    return res

res = compute_res()

with open('file.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(res)
```

Как можно добавить сюда обработку остановки скрипта, которая заключается в возврате собранного на текущий момент `res`, чтобы он сохранился в файле, а не потерялся (как это сделано для исключений `do_long_stuff`, но попытка сейчас только `1`)?

Остановка может быть закрытием окна/Ctrl+C/kill и т.п., что может сделать пользователь, системные ошибки типа "накрылся компьютер" не надо обрабатывать.

1. `atexit` и `finally` -- отрабатывает всегда, а мне надо вернуть `res` только при остановке, иначе продолжать его собирать.
2. `KeyboardInterrupt` -- только Ctrl+C + на винде плохо работает
3. `signal` -- непонятно, как вернуть `res`, + часть сигналов на винде не работают

По идее нужна какая-то комбинация подходов, чтобы работало на обеих системах.

Comment: Поменяйте подход. С некоторой регулярностью сохраняйте промежуточные значения `res` в другой файл. Тогда, даже если небо на землю рухнет у вас будет файл с результатом, например, минутной давности.

Comment: `man at_exit` Очевидно

Comment: Ещё вариант посмотреть, как обрабатывается USR1 в `dd`.

Comment: Ну и это, `SIGKILL` вы обработать не сможете.

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать `while flag:` цикл и установить в `signal_handler(signum, frame)` этот флаг в `False` с помощью `nonlocal`.

Comment: Есть готовый `at_exit()`, не надо ничего выдумывать.